# Haskell Declare empty list, but which is actually not empty?

Tags: list, haskell, filter, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to Haskell and are playing around a bit. I created a recursive function with guards. See function below:

```
filterAge :: [Person] -> [String]
filterAge (x:xs)
 | (x:xs) == []                        = []
 | (getAge x) < 30 || (getAge x) > 40  = [] ++ filterAge xs
 | otherwise                           = [getName x] ++ filterAge xs
```

I have a data set created with 10 Persons which I use in this method. When I tried this function it gave all the right people, but after that it got a Non-exhaustive patterns error: 
`["Lise","Jaap","Elle","Ebba"*** Exception: D:\...:(44,1)-(47,77): Non-exhaustive patterns in function filterAge`

I found out that it never reaches the first guard. So I played around a bit and found out something really strange (in my opinion):

```
*Main> let (x:xs) = []
*Main> (x:xs) == []
False
```

Now my main question is: Why does `(x:xs) == []` return False?

If anyone has a better way for me of doing the function that'd be great, but it's not very important.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem and Lambda.xy.x I got a quick answer to my question. This resulted in the following function which works perfectly:

```
filterAge :: [Person] -> [String]
filterAge []                           = []
filterAge (x:xs)
 | (getAge x) < 30 || (getAge x) > 40  = [] ++ filterAge xs
 | otherwise                           = [getName x] ++ filterAge xs
```

But for the best version you'd have to check the answer of Willem Van Onsem.

Comment: `(x:xs) == []` can never succeed. Since `(x:xs)` is a list with at least one element.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So I should work around it I guess? Not sure how to do that though, because I kinda need (x:xs) for my function..

Comment: To extend the answer, a list has two constructors: ```[]``` and ```_ : _```, a list with outermost constructor ```[]``` can never have ```:``` as outermost constructor.

Comment: You already pattern match in the definition of ```filterAge (x:xs)``` and exclude empty lists there. The easiest fix is to add a definition ```filterAge []``` above. Alternatively you define filterAge xs and match on arbitrary lists.

Comment: @ lambda.xy.x That works! I completely overlooked that possibilty, I have worked with that a little bit before but didn't think of it for this function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe that this mistake, namely thinking that `x:xs` can be empty, has appeared a few times already on SO. We should take a canonical question (possibly this one), and close future occurrences as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list is defined as:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

So there are two constructors for a list: `[]` the empty list, and `(x:xs)` a constructor with *one element*, and a *tail* that can store an arbitrary number (zero or more) remaining elements.

Therefore `(x:xs)` is a list **with at least one element**: the `x`. The `xs` can be an empty list (since it has type `[a]`), but `x` has type `a` so that is the "*head*" of the list. Your `let` statement works with **pattern matching**, and since the empty list cannot match with `(x:xs)`, it will always fail.

Another implication is that your **first guard can never fire**. In order to fix the issue, you should implement a separate case for the empty list. Like:

```
filterAge :: [Person] -> [String]
filterAge []     = [] -- empty list case
filterAge (x:xs) -- first guard dropped
    | (getAge x) < 30 || (getAge x) > 40  = [] ++ filterAge xs
    | otherwise                           = [getName x] ++ filterAge xs
```

Note that we dropped the first guard in the second clause, since we know that will always fail, and thus checking this will (potentially) only cost CPU cycles.

There are still some parts we can optimize:

1. we call `getAge` twice, which is useless, we can use a `where` clause to optimize this;
2. `[] ++ somelist` is simply `somelist`: appending after an empty list results in that list; and
3. `[element] ++ somelist` is `element : somelist`, since now we work with the list constructor directly.

So our `filterAge` can be rewritten into:

```
filterAge :: [Person] -> [String]
filterAge []     = [] -- empty list case
filterAge (x:xs) | age < 30 || age > 40  = filterAge xs
                 | otherwise             = getName x : filterAge xs
    where age = getAge x
```

Note that if you compile (or start the interpreter) with the `-Wincomplete-patterns` flag (*warnings* for incomplete patterns), Haskell will automatically warn you that your function definitions are not complete, and that there are input patterns for which you have not defined a clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It helps a lot, not only by giving the answer to my question but to analyze my code and to make it better. While explaining why it will be better.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your "main" question,

`*Main> let (x:xs) = []      -- (1)`

means, *when* `x`'s or `xs`'s value is required, *match* `(x:xs)` with `[]` and *use* the resulting bindings. The match will *never* succeed, and any such attempt will *always* result in patter-matching failure *error*.

So why wasn't it?

`*Main> (x:xs) == []         -- (2)`

Now this means, *try to compare* `(x:xs)` *and* `[]`. Both are lists; comparing lists involves pattern matching the top structure and then proceeding recursively  comparing the components, *on success* -- returning `False` *on failure* (not actually failing). Thus a match between `(_:_)` and `[]` is tried, and fails, resulting in an immediate *return* of the `False` value as the result of the comparison.

Note that *values* bound to **`x`** and **`xs`** were *not* requested at any point; hence there was no error because the matching of `(x:xs)` and `[]` in *`(1)`* was never triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, your answer created some more understanding for me.